# MariaDB: Command line not displaying number of rows returned

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm running MariaDB version 10.1.30, and when I run selects, updates, or alters from the command line, I would prefer to see something at the end of the process like this:

```
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

This was automatic in MySQL, but it appears to be absent from MariaDB. Is there a way to turn this on through my.cnf or some other method? This installation is part of the latest XAMPP stack for macOS.

Below is the output of `ldd mysql` from a [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 7 server which is also running MariaDB and not displaying the query summary.

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc03582000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcc30abd000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fcc308a7000)
libssl.so.10 => /lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007fcc30638000)
libcrypto.so.10 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007fcc3024e000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fcc3004a000)
libncurses.so.5 => /lib64/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007fcc2fe22000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fcc2fbf8000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fcc2f8ef000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcc2f5ec000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcc2f22b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcc3124b000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fcc2efdd000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fcc2ecf5000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fcc2eaf1000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fcc2e8bf000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fcc2e6a8000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fcc2e499000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fcc2e295000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fcc2e07a000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fcc2de53000)
libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007fcc2dbf1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

The MariaDB command line client (executable `mysql` or `mariadb` (from MariaDB v. 10.4.6)) isn't any different from MySQL in this regard. It also has all of that **by default**:

```
MariaDB [test]> insert into t1 values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from t1;
+------+
| i    |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> update t1 set i = 2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> delete from t1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select @@version;
+-----------------+
| @@version       |
+-----------------+
| 10.1.30-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you don't see that, maybe you are running the client with the `--silent` option (although it should have been obvious, because you would see more differences than just the absence of summaries):

```
MariaDB [test]> insert into t1 values (1);
MariaDB [test]> select * from t1;
i
1
MariaDB [test]> update t1 set i = 2;
MariaDB [test]> delete from t1;
MariaDB [test]>
```

The `--silent` option is **not** set by default, so if that's what you see, it must be somewhere in the configuration files.

Comment: This installation is part of the latest XAMPP stack for Mac OS, so I'm wondering if that has something to do with it. There is no reference to either silent or verbose mode in my.cnf, and there do not appear to be any custom config files.

Comment: But do you get the "silent"-looking output (bare column names and values, without the grid etc.), or do you get the normal output, only without summaries?

Comment: Normal output without the summary. It's the only thing missing. I also checked one of our production environments where we run MariaDB, and I'm seeing the same thing. Normal output, but no summary.

Comment: Does the production environment also run on Mac OS? What does the MacOS equivalent of `ldd mysql` say?

Comment: The production installation runs on CentOS 7. See my edit for the output of `ldd mysql` for the CentOS box.

Comment: That's a mystery. I've checked CentOS 7, apparently the same packages (same libraries for sure), it works fine. Can you paste somewhere the exact output that you see, starting right when you invoke `mysql` client, with all the "welcome" lines that it prints, and then a few statements which show the problem? Or not even paste, but take a screenshot of it, I think in this case it's justified. Maybe looking at the whole output, we'll guess better what's happening. Also, what shell / console / terminal / terminal settings do you use, maybe the reason is there somewhere? Did you try different ones?

Comment: I'm using a bash shell with no special setup. When I log into MariaDB, there are no welcome messages like you see in MySQL. There is only the `MariaDB[(dbname)]>` prompt. This is the case in both my MacOS environment and my CentOS environment, regardless of which terminal I log in from.